# regexp валидности скобок

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как проверить на валидность скобки? Скобки могут быть и с пробелом и без, например `( () )` либо `) () (`.

Comment: В чём ваш вопрос? Что вы пытались сделать?

Comment: @user2420249: Какой из вариантов валидный, а какой нет? `( () )`  - этот валидный?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.recursive.php

Comment: ( () ) валидный ) () ( не валидный

Comment: @user2420249: Кроме пробелом могут быть ещё какие-нибудь символы? К примеру, `( 5 * (3 + 4) )`

Comment: нет , вот примерный тест

{:expected false
    :arguments ["( )  )"]}
   {:expected true
    :arguments ["()"]}
   {:expected true
    :arguments [" ( )(  )"]}
   {:expected true
    :arguments ["(() )"]}
   {:expected false
    :arguments [") "]}
   {:expected false
    :arguments ["("]}
   {:expected false
    :arguments [") ("]}
   {:expected false
    :arguments ["(( )"]}

Но уже додумал сам спасибо

Comment: 1) в книге [Джеффри Фридл, Регулярные выражения](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4066500/) есть описание этой задачи и некоторые решения, 2) а зачем регулярки? задача и без них легко решается: заводим стек и идем по строке, если скобка открывающая - вносим в стек, если закрывающая - достаем из стека и сравниваем. Если не совпадает, либо стек пуст, либо после обработки всей строки стек наоборот не пуст - значит со скобками беда. Решение-то всего на несколько строчек

Comment: поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В PHP данную проблему легко решить с помощью *рекурсивного* регулярного выражения:

```
^[^()]*+(\((?>[^()]|(?1))*+\)[^()]*+)++$
```

См. [демо](https://regex101.com/r/fZ0iI4/1) (`\n` добавлен в демонстративных целях)

Описание рекурсивного механизма приведено на странице [**Рекурсивные шаблоны**](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.recursive.php) в [Руководстве по PHP](http://php.net/).

Шаблон находит следующее:

- `^` - начало строки
- `[^()]*+` - 0 и более символов, отличных от круглых скобок
- `(\((?>[^()]|(?1))*+\)[^()]*+)++` - (подмаска №1) 1 или более повторений

  - `\(` - открывающая круглая скобка
  - ***`(?>[^()]|(?1))*+`*** - 0 и более повторений подстроки, состоящей из символов, отличных от круглых скобок или подмаски №1
  - `\)` - закрывающая круглая скобка
  - `[^()]*+` - 0 и более символов, отличных от круглых скобок.
- `$` - конец строки.

Comment: Вот тут спасибо , полноценный ответ на мой вопрос!

Answer (score 0):

**Алгоритм только для скобок одного вида.**

Заводим счёчик. Перебираем символы по порядку. Если встретилась открывающая скобка, увеличиваем счётчик. Если закрывающая -- уменьшаем. Если после уменьшения счётчик стал отрицательным, возвращаем ошибку.
При окончании строки если счётчик не равен нулю, возвращаем ошибку.
Иначе строка валидна.

Comment: а вы учли вариант например такой ") () (" выходит что ? 0 но это же не валидно

Comment: @user2420249, читайте
> Если после уменьшения счётчик стал отрицательным, возвращаем ошибку.
Первая закрывающая скобка сделает счётчик <0 дальше цикл выполнятьтся не будет

Answer (score -1):

Напишите детерминированный/недетерминированный конечный автомат для решения этой задачи, затем сделайте из получившегося автомата - минимальный дка/нка, используя например эту статью: http://habrahabr.ru/post/166777/, потом методом исключения состояний постройте регулярное выражение, описание есть в книге Хопкрофта, или вот обсуждение http://dxdy.ru/topic77781.html. И будет вам счастье)