# Одинаковое количество открытых и закрытых скобок в строке. RegExp

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите пожалуйста регулярное выражение для проверки на одинаковое количество открытых и закрытых скобок в строке.

Comment: был такой вопрос уже не так давно, поиск по сайту вам в помощь (мне лень)) И вы бы язык указали, в общем случае не в каждом языке это можно сделать

Comment: Зачем регулярка? Чем простой подсчет не устраивает?

Comment: просто писал регулярку для остальной валидации,  и думал, что можно не делать отдельно. но наверно всё же сделаю отдельно)

Comment: Это не такая простая задача, т. к. сбалансированное скобочное выражение не описывается регулярной грамматикой. Впрочем, регулярки уже умеют в нерегулярные грамматики.

Comment: @ReinRaus как-то писал пример, поищите на сайте.

Comment: @VladD, а если как написано - просто на одинаковое количество, без сбалансированности?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Даже не задумывался. Думаю, тоже нерегулярная грамматика, т. к. потенциально бесконечное к-во состояний.

Comment: @Qwertiy А разве одинаковое количество скобок не подразумевает сбалансированность по определению?

Comment: @Alex: `()))((`

Comment: кстати, в блок "похожие" смотрели? там есть [ответ на ваш вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/461834/5079) (правда, для php). Для плюсов не знаю можно ли так же сделать, поэтому не закрываю как дубликат (хотя, возможно, стоит)

Comment: @BOPOH Для начала надо бы тот вопрос переоткрыть. Если в C используется библиотека PCRE для регулярок, то приведенное там выражение будет работать

Comment: Засыпаю. Не уверен, что все верно: https://regex101.com/r/uP1dX9/2 потестируйте, кому интересен вопрос, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

**Настоятельно не рекомендую**
решать подобные задачи при помощи регулярных выражений, если исключительно из теоретического любопытства, то для подсчета того, что в тексте одинаковое число открывающих и закрывающих скобок при помощи регулярных выражений нужно иметь в движке регулярных выражений поддержку рекурсивных шаблонов.

Первое регулярное выражение предполагает, что текст состоит исключительно из скобок:

```
(^((?:<(?2)>|>(?2)<|)++)$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/uP1dX9/2

Второе регулярное выражение допускает наличие любых других символов в тексте:

```
(^([^<>]*+(?:<(?2)>|>(?2)<|)++)[^<>]*$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/uP1dX9/3

Рекомендую обратить внимание на значение Steps. Регулярные выражения для практического применения в данном случае - худшая идея.